# How can I see username which disappeared on putty?

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, centos-7

The user name does not appear when connecting to the user via SSH. In addition, the folder I went to with the "cd" command was added to the end of the user, and now it does not appear. Have you had this problem?

image:[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvOd4.png)

Comment: Where do you expect the user name to appear? What does it mean "the folder […] was added to the end of the user, and now it does not appear"? How can a folder be added to the end of the user? Do you mean like in the prompt? In the screenshot, were literal "user" and "ip number" really there? Or are these something you added? I *guess* you added them. Were these places originally fully black? and is this what you mean by "user name does not appear"? The whole question is unclear. Please assume we know nothing about what it used to be or about your expectations. [Edit] the question and clarify.

Comment: I have modified ip adress and user for privacy. After I login via SSH I cant see username. Yesterdat everything was good. I could see username  like this: user123@123.12.55.225. For example, `cd /home/user123/web/public_html/en/`  shows it to [user123@123.5.88.45 en]

Comment: Is it about the prompt then? Do you expect something else in place of `-sh-4.2`? Is `sh` the expected shell in the first place? or were you expecting (e.g.) `bash`? It's still not clear what you are expecting instead of what.

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/SXGX9sH/ssh-hata.png . I am expecting to see username in terminal.

Comment: OK, now it's getting better. You should improve the question by [edit]ing it, not by writing comments. What is the output of `echo "$0"`? What shell did you expect? I can fix the prompt but maybe the poor prompt is only a symptom of unexpected shell. After you invoke your expected shell by hand (e.g. `bash`), is the prompt right?

Comment: output of echo "$0" is -sh

Comment: For the third time: please [edit] the question and add all the information there. To diagnose the problem further: what is the output of `echo "$SHELL"`? `grep '^peskirpiko:' /etc/passwd | cut -d : -f 7`?

Comment: This is just  a matter of setting the prompt, which is done with `export PS1='\u@\h:\w\$` or equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Thank you for all helpers. My English is not good enough sorry for this. I have solved my problem by changing SSH Access method on user editing page in VestaPanel. I have closed SSH access by select nologin and saved. Then I set bash again and saved thus my problem has solved.

Image: [VestaCP related field SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acog9.png)

Image2: [Putty SSH connection last state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fedu.png)

my .bashrc file:

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi

# Uncomment the following line if you don't like systemctl's auto-paging feature:
# export SYSTEMD_PAGER=

# User specific aliases and functions
```